# Loading a pickle in subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, pickle

So I am trying to pickle a large dictionary that includes:
 numpy arrays,
 other dictionaries,
 filenames,
 and simple variables.

But when I boot up a subprocess that will load the data, I'm getting an 'insecure string pickle' error.

If I kill the main process before it calls the subprocess, and I run it manually through command line, it works fine...

The problem may lie with the PIPE-ing with stdout and stderr.

I've tried playing with some protocols for the pickle dump, but to no avail.

Here's a sample from my code:

```
    dataout = open('Dataout.pickle','wb')
    dictout = { dict of all the values }
    pickle.dump(dictout, dataout)
    for i in xrange(int(self.runs)):
        self.names.append("%s_%i"%(self.name,i))
        if self.rerun == 0:
            self.chains.append(subprocess.Popen('python BaSIC_Model.py %s'%self.names[i], shell=False,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,universal_newlines=True))#bufsize=0,

        else:
            self.chains.append(subprocess.Popen('python BaSIC_Model.py %s'%self.names[i], shell=False,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True))#bufsize=0,

    if self.Gui == 1:
        self.cp = Cust_Progress.ProgRun("Running Chains", [0]*int(self.runs),self.itter)
        self.cp.Play()
        while True:
            if not any([True if chain.poll() == None else False for chain in self.chains]):
                print 'broke'
                texts = [chain.stdout.read() for chain in self.chains]
                print texts[0]
                break
            texts = [chain.stdout.readline() for chain in self.chains]
            print texts[0]
            if texts == None or None in texts:
                texts = [0]*len(self.chains)
            self.cp.UpdateIters(texts)
            wx.Yield()
            time.sleep(0.05)
        self.cp.Done()
        self.cp.UpdateIters(['Generating Plots']*int(self.runs))
```

And from the subprocess, it fails on:

```
    inFile = open('Dataout.pickle','rb')
    inputData = pickle.load(inFile)
```

with the insecure string pickle error.
also, my self.cp from the code is a custom progress that I have, which will generate the progress based off the stdout from each of my subprocess'. I have a working version with Threaded classes, but it is dreadfully slow, and a subprocessed version would give me at least 5x (to 9x) the speed if I am running 5 subprocesses at the same time.

Has anyone else had a problem loading a pickle file in a subprocess before? 
I've had programs that subprocessed and could load a pickle, but never with a PIPE to stdout.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rookie mistake...

Wasn't calling:

```
    dataout.close()
```

after the dump.... -_-